# Can Windows 7 use both wired LAN and Wi-Fi at the same time?

Tags: networking, windows-7, wifi, lan

I want to do this because the Wi-Fi system at work has a lot of bandwidth, but it's shared and each individual connection is highly throttled (like dial-up on a noisy connection).  Few people are on the network at night, but the connections are still throttled.  I can however connect to one router on LAN and also connect to another router on Wi-Fi.  Theoretically that could double my bandwidth, but Windows seems to only want to use one or the other.  Is there a way to use them both simultaneously?

Comment: After quite a bit of research, it seems that it's not possible, perhaps because Windows gets confused over which connection to use (it seems to prefer wired over wireless, most of the time).  Windows 10 can't do it either.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, from my own experience, I believe this is impossible without third-party software.

Comment: Do you know of any third-party software than can do this?

Comment: @HypnoToad, From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0):

no you can't.  you can only connect one network either lan or wifi.
If you want to share your wifi connection with other pc locally you can connnect 2 pc using ethernet cable and create bridge connection.This is how you can share you internet and can connect both.